# Datadog Agent Error : Unable to collect configurations from provider docker: temporary failure in dockerutil

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, datadog, typhoon-kubernetes

Datadog installation: using helm was successful

- [Docs used](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/kubernetes/?tab=helm)
- Agent version (7.19.0)

Agent Status

```sh
$ kubectl exec -it datadog-release-7jttj agent status | egrep "OK|ERROR"        
Defaulting container name to agent.
Use 'kubectl describe pod/datadog-release-7jttj -n default' to see all of the containers in this pod.
      Instance ID: cpu [OK]
      Instance ID: disk:e5dffb8bef24336f [OK]
      Instance ID: docker [ERROR]
      Instance ID: file_handle [OK]
      Instance ID: io [OK]
      Instance ID: kubelet:d884b5186b651429 [OK]
      Instance ID: kubernetes_apiserver [OK]
      Instance ID: load [OK]
      Instance ID: memory [OK]
      Instance ID: network:e0204ad63d43c949 [OK]
      Instance ID: ntp:d884b5186b651429 [OK]
      Instance ID: uptime [OK]
```

Error in Logs

```sh
$ kubectl logs -f datadog-release-7jttj agent | grep "ERROR"
2020-05-03 14:49:17 UTC | CORE | ERROR | (pkg/collector/runner/runner.go:292 in work) | Error running check docker: temporary failure in dockerutil, will retry later: try delay not elapsed yet
2020-05-03 14:49:18 UTC | CORE | ERROR | (pkg/autodiscovery/config_poller.go:123 in collect) | Unable to collect configurations from provider docker: temporary failure in dockerutil, will retry later: try delay not elapsed yet
2020-05-03 14:49:19 UTC | CORE | ERROR | (pkg/autodiscovery/config_poller.go:123 in collect) | Unable to collect configurations from provider docker: temporary failure in dockerutil, will retry later: try delay not elapsed yet
2020-05-03 14:49:20 UTC | CORE | ERROR | (pkg/autodiscovery/config_poller.go:123 in collect) | Unable to collect configurations from provider docker: temporary failure in dockerutil, will retry later: try delay not elapsed yet
2020-05-03 14:49:21 UTC | CORE | ERROR | (pkg/autodiscovery/config_poller.go:123 in collect) | Unable to collect configurations from provider docker: temporary failure in dockerutil, will retry later: try delay not elapsed yet
2020-05-03 14:49:22 UTC | CORE | ERROR | (pkg/autodiscovery/config_poller.go:123 in collect) | Unable to collect configurations from provider docker: temporary failure in dockerutil, will retry later: try delay not elapsed yet
2020-05-03 14:49:23 UTC | CORE | ERROR | (pkg/autodiscovery/config_poller.go:123 in collect) | Unable to collect configurations from provider docker: temporary failure in dockerutil, will retry later: try delay not elapsed yet
```

ERROR which i see in log agent and the same is true for all pods

```sh
 default/datadog-release-7jttj/init-config
  -----------------------------------------
    Type: file
    Path: /var/log/pods/default_datadog-release-7jttj_b373c792-b5da-46b9-a906-1fd71e9a41bc/init-config/*.log
    Status: Error: could not find any file matching pattern /var/log/pods/default_datadog-release-7jttj_b373c792-b5da-46b9-a906-1fd71e9a41bc/init-config/*.log, check that all its subdirectories are executable
      0 files tailed out of 0 files matching
```

Not sure where I am going wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to go through datadog [log collection troubleshooting](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/log-collection-troubleshooting-guide/#permission-issues-while-tailing-log-files) guide? As mentioned here The datadog-agent does not run as root. For this reason, when you configure your datadog-agent to tail log files (for custom logs or for integrations) you need to take special care to ensure the datadog-agent user has read access to tail the log files you want to collect from. Could you try to add the missing permissions via the chmod command and let me know if that worked?

Comment: yes @jt97, I have tried running the command "chmod -R 755 <absolute-path>" in one of the worker nodes but still the logs are not shipping.

Comment: Did you update your values.yaml to enable log collection as mentioned [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/kubernetes/log/?tab=helm)?

Comment: yes @it97, that was done as well.

Comment: @codeaprendiz Did this ever get solved?

Comment: Yes @joshk132, it was resolved. I think it was something related with SELinux Enabled for which datadog has different config. I am not sure though. You can also try [helm installation](https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts) or reach out to their support team for the same.